# Надо ли в школе изучать грамматику и орфографию?

Tags: методика

В последнее время все чаще стали звучать разговоры о том, что  научить  школьников  грамотному письму становится всё сложнее;  что на это тратится всё учебное время, а результат оставляет желать лучшего.  Даже задается вопрос:  может быть, не стоит учитывать грамотность не предстоящем в 11 классе сочинении? Пусть учащиеся не чувствуют скованности при написании текста, пусть свободно излагают свои мысли.

Да и вообще,  грамотная речь – это, прежде всего, правильно построенная устная речь  (и только потом уже записанная)  – вот чему надо учить.   Зачем  подробно изучать грамматику,  делать  разного рода разборы, пусть этим занимаются   профессиональные лингвисты, а остальным людям  знать грамматические тонкости  незачем. А то в результате они не умеют ни говорить, ни писать.

И вопрос:  А можно ли вообще без знания грамматики  (хотя бы на школьном уровне) научить людей  разных профессий  свободно, красиво и грамотно говорить (ведь важен-то практический результат)? И если это возможно, то, может быть,  следует  простить им  не очень грамотную письменную речь, пусть корректоры занимаются ее правкой?

Comment: Сейчас опять вернули сочинения в 11 классе? Их вроде бы отменяли в связи с ЕГЭ.

Comment: Кажется, сочинение собираются писать  зимой в качестве допуска к ЕГЭ, но оценивать его будут по системе зачет/незачет.

Comment: Предположим,  человек  научится  правильно  излагать  свои  мысли  устно,  но  как  он  их  запишет  без  помощи  грамматики,  орфографии  и  пунктуации.

Comment: Учащиеся должны хорошо освоить базовый курс всех этих наук, сейчас такой базы просто нет. Нет кратких справочников по грамматике, пунктуации и орфографии, основной и дополнительный материалы в   учебниках перемешаны, не сведены в систему. Обычный грамотный человек обладает именно базовыми знаниями, вряд ли он, к примеру,  возьмется редактировать художественную литературу. Поэтому не стоит требовать от школьников абсолютной грамотности.

Comment: Абсолютной  и  не  надо.

Comment: В школьном тексте будут отмечены все ошибки, как и в любом другом тексте, это и есть абсолютные требования. Поэтому учащимся приходится его упрощать, а это отрицательно сказывается на их умении писать и говорить. К примеру, в античном обществе грамматику изучали на примере разбора поэзии Гомера, при этом риторика считалась ведущей дисциплиной, а искусство речи было важнейшей предпосылкой успеха свободного гражданина в общественной и политической жизни.

Comment: Этот метод было бы неплохо использовать при составлении наших учебников по грамматике, в которых вместо Гомера часто приводятся искусственные  учебные примеры, бесцветные по содержанию и сомнительные по форме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы писать хорошие стихи, не обязательно уметь отличать ямб от хорея, но нужно чувствовать ритм. Для того чтобы грамотно и красиво говорить, не обязательно понимать, чем отличается  причастный оборот от деепричастного, а обстоятельство от дополнения, но нужно чувствовать грамматический строй фразы и соблюдать логику повествования. Орфографические ошибки это вообще отдельный разговор, так как даже современные автокорректоры их по большей части исправляют, а если приходиться много писать, то поневоле все основные слова запомнишь.

Итак, мы можем научить детей грамотному построению фразы, не углубляясь в грамматические дебри, но необходимо разработать методику. По-моему, лучший способ научиться правильно строить фразу, это сочинения, как устные, так и письменные, в результате которых ребёнок сам придёт к оптимальному способу построения собственных фраз. Упор на занятиях в этом случае должен делаться на стилистику, с богатым материалом текстов разных авторов и стилей, а также ошибки в построении фраз и расширение словарного запаса. Недостатки орфографической грамотности в этом случае в основном нивелируются современными технологиями, а пунктуацию, по большому счёту, и так мало кто понимает. Так что в целом в этой идее есть резон, но предварительно требуется разработать соответствующую новым требованиям методику и опробовать её. При существующей системе подобное не имеет никакого смысла и даже вредно для системы обучения.

Comment: Мне наиболее близка Ваша точка зрения. В нашем обучении много формализма, мы как будто забываем, что мы носители языка и способны многое усваивать на интуитивном уровне.(Это все равно что учить музыке путем запоминания нажимаемых клавиш). Грамматический материал расширенного плана (кроме грамматического минимума) должен изучаться на практических примерах, когда возникает в этом необходимость (чтобы понять красоту слога классика или чтобы объяснить реальные речевые ошибки).

Comment: Что касается пунктуации, то она полностью отражает грамматику и не требует особых правил (но эта мысль, к сожалению, еще недостаточно осознана обществом).

Comment: >> мы как будто забываем, что мы носители языка и способны многое усваивать на интуитивном уровне.

Например, ваши тонические ударения. ))))

>> Что касается пунктуации, то она полностью отражает грамматику и не требует особых правил

Это вы или нет? "Пунктуация отражает грамматику" – удивительная по бессмысленности фраза.

Comment: Ну да, вот Вы, к примеру, в своей речи используете фразы восходящей и нисходящей интонации, но даже не замечаете этого. Это и есть интуиция.  Понаблюдайте за детьми, которые осваивают язык, ведь им никто не объясняет грамматические правила. Дети просто радуются возможности говорить, а взрослые, разделяя их радость, мягко поправляют речь. Почему бы в школах не использовать ту же методику: больше говорить и ненавязчиво (без строгих оценок) поправлять.

Comment: Интуиция – это не есть нечто туманное и необъяснимое, это – надо больше читать, и желательно с детства, и желательно с раннего, вот и все.

>> Почему бы в школах не использовать ту же методику: больше говорить и ненавязчиво (без строгих оценок) поправлять.

И в математике так же. И по другим предметам. Больше игры, и пусть детство заканчивается лет в сорок. А до этого – никаких строгих оценок! Вдруг дитё разнервничается, а ему ещё дома два сериала смотреть...

Answer (score 3):

> > А можно ли вообще без знания грамматики (хотя бы на школьном уровне) научить людей разных профессий свободно, красиво и грамотно говорить (ведь важен-то практический результат)? И если это возможно, то, может быть, следует простить им не очень грамотную письменную речь, пусть корректоры занимаются ее правкой?

Красиво - не надо. Друг мой Аркадий, не говори красиво!

Корректоров не хватит. И нужны будут не корректоры, а полноценные редакторы, которые не убежавшие запятые ловят, а слетевшие шляпы у подъезжающих к станцыи.

> > Да и вообще, грамотная речь – это, прежде всего, правильно построенная устная речь (и только потом уже записанная) – вот чему надо учить.

А вот это две большие разницы: устная и письменная. И учить правильной устной - еще и похлеще, чем правильной письменной. В смысле - труднее. В письменной-то можно побекать-помекать (т.е. подумать), да и исправить всегда можно, а тут: полез в кузов - не говори, что не груздь! В смысле - некогда репу чесать, говори быстрей! И помни, что слово не воробей.

А правильная устная речь всегда держалась на правильной письменной. Не наоборот.

В школе не столько дают конкретные знания, сколько развивают интеллект. Причем развивают с разных сторон. Так вот, грамматика - очень важная сторона, не уступит математике. Узкий специалист подобен флюсу, интеллект, заточенный на что-то одно, всегда будет уступать разностороннему. Бегун-марафонец занимается и штангой тоже.

Конкретно синусы будут нужны далеко не каждому, конкретно ЖИ и ШИ - буквально всем.
Можно возразить, что ЖИ и ШИ уж будут всегда писать правильно. Отвечаю: нет! Стоит еще снизить планку, перестать "учитывать грамотность", как через 10 лет о нынешней ситуации будут вспоминать с ностальгией. Мол, были люди в наше время, корову правильно писали!

ЗЫ. Забавно, что с подобными предложениями выступают почти исключительно люди малограмотные. Вспоминая свои мучения в школе, они хотят избавить от подобных мучений своих детей... и внуков... Софию в этом заподозрить вряд ли можно. Тогда зачем?

Comment: София пересказывает мнение тех людей, которые имеют непосредственное отношение к системе образования (их, наверное, тоже нельзя заподозрить в малограмотности). Им же результат нужен, а хорошего результата нет.Даже сам министр образования высказался на эту тему: "Грамотность не важна. Дмитрий Ливанов предложил внести коррективы в нынешнюю систему оценки уровня грамотности сочинений". http://www.city-n.ru/view/345842.html

Comment: Что важнее - письменная речь или  устная? Вот вдохновленный автор пишет произведение, придает материальную форму образам и идеям - вряд ли он в процессе творчества много думает о запятых. А вот корректор и редактор придают рукописи должный вид: правят грамматику, орфографию, пунктуацию.  Теперь пред нами образец правильной речи – это устная речь разного стиля, запечатленная в буквенных знаках.
А школьникам как быть? Можно ли им на уроках позволить себе немного вдохновения? Вряд ли, ведь с них требуют абсолютную грамотность корректора и редактора, им бы ошибок поменьше сделать.

Comment: Хотелось бы более достоверной информации. Не знаю, как вам, а мне достаточно было глянуть на то фото, чтобы доверие к сайту сему как-то резко упало.

Неужели вы не понимаете, что важна даже не сама по себе грамматика. А то, что с её помощью прокачиваются мозги. Наряду с математикой, физикой, биологией, историей и литературой. Хотя и сама по себе она весьма важна. Иначе как, я вас спрашиваю, отличить дурака от умного?

Ладно, это хохма. А вот это уже не хохма. Скажите, лично вам нужен эталон метра? Вряд ли... Делаете ли вы вывод, что он не нужен ВАЩЕ?

Comment: С грамматикой ведь то же самое. Мы уничтожаем стандарт. Пишите, как хотите. Но не удивляйтесь, что через короткое время ваш метр превратится в 90 см, а потом и в 70. Как штаны-то шить будете?!

Comment: >> Вот вдохновленный автор пишет произведение, придает материальную форму образам и идеям - вряд ли он в процессе творчества много думает о запятых

Это верно. Вряд ли думает. Он о них много и хорошо думал раньше – когда учился в литинституте, или на филфаке университета, или на журфаке университета...

Хотя сейчас такие попадаются аффтары, что боже мой... Им и правда нужна армия редакторов и корректоров. Может, эта самая армия и лоббирует отмену грамматики, э? Хотят быть как жрецы в Древнем Египте? Не выйдет-с. )))

Comment: Уважаемый Niemand, я полностью разделяю Вашу мысль о пользе грамматических знаний, я даже считаю, что орфография и пунктуация практически следуют из грамматики, хотя их обычно представляют как самостоятельные разделы.  Речь идет о том, как наилучшим образом все это усвоить. Если мы имеем плохие результаты, то надо думать о причинах, менять методику.  Что касается источников, то мнение Ливанова широко обсуждается в Сети. Хуже то, что среди лингвистов есть известные люди, которым формальная грамматика кажется ненужной.

Comment: Причины исключительно просты. Школьники не учатся. Во-первых, много развлечений, во-вторых – они предоставлены сами себе. Есть и в-третьих, и в-четвертых, но сложность грамматики тут ну абсолютно ни при чем. Сильно усложнилась грамматика за последние 30 лет? Об этом даже говорить смешно.

Кто учится – тот усваивает. В этом году в Питере количество сдавших на 90 и больше баллов – очень много, я даже удивился. Думаю, что в Москве ситуация не хуже. А подстраиваться под бездельников и дебилов, это, знаете ли...

Answer (score 2):

Скажите, София, а алгебре детей тоже учить не надо? Или, скажем, абсолютно "бесполезный" предмет - география ("извозчик довезёт")?
**Все** "знания", даваемые в школе, по большей части, бесполезны. Но они определённым образом "форматируют" мозг. И орфография - один из способов такого "форматирования". Дело, как Вы понимаете, не в "запятых", а в "разборе" слова или предложения. Именно **он** является наиболее ценной частью обучения... И наиболее "бесполезной" с точки зрения "взрослой жизни".

Comment: Думаю, что содержание любого школьного предмета можно разделить на две части: теоретическую, развивающую мышление, и практическую, которая может применяться в жизни и поэтому вызывает больший интерес. К примеру, в математике преобладает первое, развивающее назначение, хотя практические задачи тоже решаются. Что касается грамматики, то там нет необходимости выделения ее в обособленную дисциплину, предназначенную только для развития ума.

Comment: Гораздо  важнее показать, как грамматика связана с правописанием, каким образом грамматические знания  используются при построении любого текста по следующему принципу: не знаешь базовой грамматики - не умеешь правильно говорить.

Comment: Моя жена страдает дисграфией. Однако, это не помешало ей получить высшее образование. Так что правописание, при всей своей значимости, **не является** "жизненно необходимым" предметом. А связь правописания и грамотного построения фраз - спорна.  
Гораздо важнее - развить способность к анализу, без которой во "взрослой" жизни обойтись трудно. А это достигается через постоянный анализ. Слова, предложения, рассказа, математической формулы, геометрической или физической задачи, химического процесса, взаимосвязей между географическими и экономическими особенностями...

Comment: Речь идет об использовании грамматических знаний  как при построении устной речи, так и при ее записи. К сожалению, пользователи языка роль грамматики недооценивают. Представьте себе, что грамматические разборы отменят, считая их ненужными. Тогда мы останемся с правилами письма, которые будем учить исключительно наизусть, и с речевыми ошибками, которые не сможем объяснить. Грамматика - это фундамент, на котором строится язык. Также с сожалением можно отметить, что, по мнению пользователей, "связь правописания и грамотного построения фраз - спорна".

Comment: Такому мнению способствует  формулировка наших правил, основанных на грамматике, но представленных независимо от нее. В действительности русская система письма дает нам уникальную возможность именно записи устной речи. Это делается путем разделения текстового материала на обозначение звука по слуху  в сильной позиции и восстановления его (правило, проверка, словарь) в слабой позиции. Что касается пунктуации, то грамматика, а также нелюбимая всеми интонация дают возможность оформить письмо без особого труда, без зубрежки правил, в полном соответствии с замыслом автора.

Comment: Связь правописания и грамотного построения фраз **действительно** спорна. По крайней мере, люди, **вообще** не умевшие писать, вполне сносно изъяснялись в устной речи. А если грамматические разборы отменят - выпускники школ просто станут чуть-чуть тупее. И общее ухудшение грамотности будет **наименьшей** из бед, которые при этом возникнут.

Comment: Вы просто "ставите лошадь впереди телеги". На самом деле, **не важно**, сколько ошибок человек делает в слове "ещё". Важно - как он воспринимает, обрабатывает и излагает информацию. И правописание может лишь замедлить этот процесс. А, вот, ослабление аналитических навыков - его разрушит.

Answer (score 1):

Всплыл этот вопрос, почитал ответы - ни один меня в достаточной мере не устроил.

Как я написал в комментарии к одному ответу, автор вопроса, путает, похоже, грамотность с грамматикой. Грамотным вполне можно быть "от рождения", не изучая грамматики (пусть это и редкость большая в силу сложившихся подходов, которые все равно требуют изучения грамматики). Но вопрос-то стоит не так. По сути спрашивается, можно ли считать образование полноценным без знания обучающимся основ грамматики родного языка.

И тут я против отхода от "традиционных ценностей". 
Разумеется, речь не идет об изучении всеми и каждым грамматики в академическом объеме (который, кстати, тоже непостоянен, что-то пересматривается в силу естественного развития языка, что-то - в силу новых наработок и подходов, так что изучить **полностью** грамматику невозможно даже теоретически). Т. е. вопрос только в том объеме, который необходим любому взрослому человеку для полноценного владения собственным языком.

Грамматику же учат не просто для того, чтобы усвоить, скажем, падежи, но при необходимости понять и разобраться в том, что говорится в словарях, справочниках, объяснится в нестандартной ситуации, постичь смысл прочитанного, не тратя слишком много времени, грамотно составить какой-то документ (заявление, объяснительную, завещание), не всегда же под рукой есть шаблон и знакомый юрист. И это все - в первую очередь грамматика, не просто общая грамотность.

Вот такой необходимый для удовлетворения этих и подобных потребностей минимум грамматических знаний должен остаться в программе в любом случае. 
А конкретный объем этих базово-необходимых знаний можно пересматривать, да.

*Сейчас, с приходом совершенно одиозного министра, вопрос совсем не праздный. Ролики на ю-тюбе о новых веяниях в образовательной науке, от которых волосы дыбом встают, всегда доступны.

Вот примерчик свежий, не совсем про русский язык, но и про него тоже.* 
https://youtu.be/VeajpI6aCwM
*Нет, пусть уж лучше по-старому учат, чем такое слышать.*

Comment: Ну, это шизофрения конкретного преподавателя, причём думаю, что начальной школы (такой историк институт бы не закончил).

Comment: @МаркИз, это вообще-то только пример того, до чего можно докатиться на пути образовательного нигилизма. Мам по себе он не предмет обсуждения в этой теме, хотя подобного можно найти в сети немало. У меня тезис был глобальный, что грамматика в каком-то объеме всё-таки нужна даже в начальной школе и частный тезис, что образовательный нигилизм до добра не доводит. Обсуждать эту даму в отрыве от этих тезисов не имею ни малейшего намеренья. А вот в рамках этих тезисов - показательно. А что шизофрения - никто и не сомневается.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что есть необходимый минимум знаний, без которого нельзя выдавать аттестат зрелости. Может быть, стоит пересмотреть программу и избавить школьников от погружения в глубины лингвистики. Однако писать кАрова и не ставить запятую перед "что" все-таки неприлично. Ну, потому что...:) Ведь практического смысла в умении складывать простые числа тоже никакого: сейчас в каждом телефоне калькулятор. И то, что Земля круглая, в обычной жизни не пригодится. Так что? Даешь Митрофанушку?

Comment: Какие глубины лингвистики, вы о чем?! В школе дают основы грамматики, азы!

>> Однако писать кАрова и не ставить запятую перед "что" все-таки неприлично. Ну, потому что...:)

Да не "ну, потому что", а по вполне реальной причине. Осязаемой. Общество оценивает интеллект своих членов в том числе и по умению грамотно писать. Так уж получилось. И это очень даже не лишено. Связь прямая! Исключения крайне редки.

Comment: Мне кажется верной мысль о необходимом минимуме грамматических и орфографических знаний, который нужно знать на отлично.  Нужны такие грамматические словари, их объем может быть очень невелик, в то время как сейчас необходимая и факультативная информация без всякого различия просто "размазана" по учебникам разных классов. Надо менять методику обучения: чтобы освободить школьников от зажатости и скованности, надо строго требовать от них только базовые знания. Но этот минимум они действительно обязаны освоить.

Comment: Видно, что вы страшно далеки от школьников... Где вы видели их зажатыми?! Гораздо чаще они развязно-расслабленно-разнузданные! И на уроки, в том числе русского языка, им плевать с высокой колокольни. Во всяком случае, те, кто балансирует на грани необходимого минимума баллов, именно таковы.

Comment: Я имела в виду - от зажатости и скованности при написании тематических текстов, а Вы почему-то говорите о поведении школьников на уроках.

Comment: Я думаю, что каждый сталкивается с проблемой грамотной записи устной речи, когда хочется сохранить ее выразительность, но при этом не нарушить орфографические правила. Чем меньше уровень грамотности, тем хуже и беднее получается запись, сложные выражения заменяются более простыми и стандартными. Вот это и есть зажатость и скованность.

Comment: Повторяю: школьники, у которых грамотность хромает на обе ноги, ничуть не испытывают ни зажатости, ни скованности. По очень простой причине: им плевать. Ну как правило. Нет, если родители пообещали новый айфон, если будет не двойка, то они могут зажаться... Но как правило такого не бывает.

Я вот не пойму: зачем оглядываться на слабых? И еще одного не пойму, а вы так и не ответили: что, за последние 30 лет наша грамматика так неимоверно усложнилась, что ее школьный вариант надо срочно бежать упрощать? В чем причина падения грамотности? По-моему, ответ совершенно ясен, и я его уже здесь давал.

Comment: Грамматика не усложнилась, просто ставится вопрос о необходимости грамматических разборов, которые, как правило, проводятся  формально и не связаны напрямую с решением практических задач как в письменной, так и в устной речи. Именно эти разборы предлагается исключить. Носители языка владеют речью и без знания грамматики, вот и обсуждается вопрос о том, в каком объеме ее следует изучать.

Comment: Так почему раньше были необходимы эти разборы, а теперь перестали быть?
Ну и пусть напрямую не связаны (хотя как сказать), зато мозг прокачивают!

Опять "и без знания грамматики"... Без знания географии (даже кургузой школьной) человек вполне может прожить — его всюду довезут. Ну железный же довод! Чем он хуже вашего? Ладно, не будем грамматику, не будем синусы (зачем они?), не будем географическое положение Китая... Что будем-то? Чем будем прокачивать мозги? Именно это основная задача школы, наряду с приучением к жизни в коллективе.

Answer (score 0):

Может я не в тему, но когда учился, не понимал смысла изучать падежи; казалось интуитивно как правильно говорить без знания того какой падеж используешь.  Мне кажется грамматический разбор нужен когда учишь иностранный язык.  Когда учишь родной язык, разбор на таком уровне нужен только будущим преподавателям.

Comment: Ну как вам сказать... Не совсем в тему. Вы, вслед за автором вопроса,  путаете, похоже, грамотность с грамматикой. Грамотным вполне можно быть "от рождения", не изучая грамматики (пусть это и редкость большая в силу сложившихся подходов, которые все равно требуют изучения грамматики). Но вопрос-то стоит не так. По сути спрашивается, можно ли считать  образование полноценным без знание обучающимся основ грамматики родного языка. И вот тут ваши рассуждения не по теме, да.